# image field url changes as soon as I override list method in Django viewsets

Tags: python, django, image, rest

I am new to python and so django. I added a image field in my model...

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  body = MarkdownField()
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
```

Then, when I write my simple django rest view like as shown, it works fine.

```
class EntryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
```

Here, the image field in django rest API is being shown like:

"image": "http://localhost:8000/media/images/x_4.jpg",

Now, when I override the list mthod in view the server url part i.e. "http://localhost:8000" is gone and remaining is left.
The new view as I mentioned is:

```
class EntryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
    lookup_field = 'title'

    def list(self, request,*kwargs):
        queryset=Entry.objects.filter(publish=True)
        serializer = EntrySerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and the image field in django rest API as I mentioned, becomes this:

"image": "/media/images/x_4.jpg",

I want the complete URL in image field in API when I override the list method.

help!

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ModelViewSet` is passing request into your serializer, so serializer can built URLs based on current domain. Without request, `EntrySerializer` have no idea about domain, so it is creating domain-less URLs.

You can fix it in several ways:

1. instead of overwriting `list` method, overwrite get_queryset like this:

   ```
   class EntryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = Entry.objects.all()
       serializer_class = EntrySerializer
       lookup_field = 'title'

       def get_queryset(self):
           return super(EntryView, self).filter(publish=True)
   ```
2. Use get_serializer method of ModelViewSet instead of using EntrySerializer directly:

   ```
   class EntryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = Entry.objects.all()
       serializer_class = EntrySerializer
       lookup_field = 'title'

       def list(self, request,*kwargs):
           queryset=Entry.objects.filter(publish=True)
           serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset,many=True)
           return Response(serializer.data)
   ```
3. pass dictionary containing current request into context kwarg of your serializer:

   ```
   class EntryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = Entry.objects.all()
       serializer_class = EntrySerializer
       lookup_field = 'title'

       def list(self, request,*kwargs):
           queryset=Entry.objects.filter(publish=True)
           serializer = EntrySerializer(queryset,many=True, context={'request': request})
           return Response(serializer.data)
   ```

First method is most recommended, last one is least recommended, because there are more default methods inside ModelViewSet that won't be affected by changes inside list method. Also there are more default variables passed inside serializer by default.